# Issue using NodeJS Kafka and Docker, the resolved host is container ID

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, centos, docker-compose

I have a CentOS 7.5 VM running and I am trying to run a ZooKeeper/Kafka server into a container (with docker compose).

I am using kafka-node(2.6.1) to use Kafka. Everything works fine when running on the VM directly. But when the Kafak server is dockerized, there is an issue related to IPv6.

I can create topics on the Kafka server when I use the `/bin/kafka-topics.sh` script when being outside the container (on the host) meaning that the container is OK and the port (2181, 9092) are opened.

Here is the versions I'm using :

```js
//CentOS Version
SB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description:    CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core)
Release:        7.5.1804
Codename:       Core

//nodejs verison
5.3.0

//kafka version
2.11-2.0.0

// docker version
Client:
 Version:           18.06.0-ce
 API version:       1.38
 Go version:        go1.10.3
 Git commit:        0ffa825
 Built:             Wed Jul 18 19:08:18 2018
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false
Server:
 Engine:
  Version:          18.06.0-ce
  API version:      1.38 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.10.3
  Git commit:       0ffa825
  Built:            Wed Jul 18 19:10:42 2018
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
  
//docker compose version
docker-compose version 1.21.2, build a133471
docker-py version: 3.4.1
CPython version: 2.7.5
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
```

Here is my nodejs script that works fine when the kafka is on the host but not when the kafka is in docker :

```js
var fs = require('fs'),
    kafka = require('kafka-node'),
    path = require('path'),
    cassandra = require('cassandra-driver'),
    moment = require('moment');
//Producer
const client = new kafka.Client("127.0.0.1:2181");

const producer = new kafka.HighLevelProducer(client);
var interval;
console.log('Hello');

producer.on("ready", function () {
    console.log("Ingestion Complete Event Producer is connected and ready.");
    interval = setInterval(function () {
        _scanDirectoryAndTagReport();
    }, (process.argv[2] || 1500));
});
producer.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log('error', err);
    
});
```

And here is the output i'm having when I run this script from the VM :

```js
Hello
Ingestion Complete Event Producer is connected and ready.
error { Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND d98e973bc4a7 d98e973bc4a7:9092
    at errnoException (dns.js:28:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:79:26)
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'd98e973bc4a7',
  host: 'd98e973bc4a7',
  port: '9092' } 
error { Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND d98e973bc4a7 d98e973bc4a7:9092
    at errnoException (dns.js:28:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:79:26)
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'd98e973bc4a7',
  host: 'd98e973bc4a7',
  port: '9092' } 
  error { Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND d98e973bc4a7 d98e973bc4a7:9092
    at errnoException (dns.js:28:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:79:26)
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'd98e973bc4a7',
  host: 'd98e973bc4a7',
  port: '9092' } 
  error { Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND d98e973bc4a7 d98e973bc4a7:9092
    at errnoException (dns.js:28:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:79:26)
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'd98e973bc4a7',
  host: 'd98e973bc4a7',
  port: '9092' } 
  error { Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND d98e973bc4a7 d98e973bc4a7:9092
    at errnoException (dns.js:28:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:79:26)
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'd98e973bc4a7',
  host: 'd98e973bc4a7',
  port: '9092' } 
  error { Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND d98e973bc4a7 d98e973bc4a7:9092
    at errnoException (dns.js:28:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:79:26)
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'd98e973bc4a7',
  host: 'd98e973bc4a7',
  port: '9092' }
```

The error message is looping.

Someone have a lead ?

have a nice day,

NeitoFR

Edit 1 : As pointed out in the comment it is not a IPv6 related issue but the problem is that the resolved host by my producer is the container ID

Comment: Are you sure that that is the code you're running? I see you posted `const client = new kafka.Client("127.0.0.1:2181");` But the error message indicates that something is trying to connect to `"d98e973bc4a7:9092"`. I also don't see anything relevant to IPv6 here. So I don't understand why it's tagged IPv6?

Comment: Well the script log `Ingestion Complete Event Producer is connected and ready.`, this is logged when the 'ready' event is thrown, the ready events is (I assume) thrown when my client successfully connected to the kafka server.
What make me sa that it is IPv6 related is that the error is connected to an GetAddrInfo Exception and that the returned string  really looks like hexadecimal code(and so an IPv6 substring). 

I totally agree this is far fetched and certainly incorrect but it is what it looked like

Comment: That's not an IPv6 address. It doesn't even look like one. It looks like a Docker container ID.

Comment: You were right, it is actually the ID of kafka's container, still have no clue on how to solve this

Comment: It came to my attention because I follow the [tag:ipv6] tag. But I would suggest also posting your `docker-compose.yml`.

Answer (score 1):

I found one solution, you can specify a hostname in your docker-compose.yml and set the nodejs client to connect to that hostname.

Here is the .yml :

```js
version: '3'

services:
  kafkazoo:
    build: ./kafka
    hostname: kafkazoo
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
      - 2181:2181
  data_input_service:
    build: ./data_input_service
    # environment:
    #   - SCRIPT_NAME=pull_data_service.js
    volumes: 
      - /predix/shared/linux_shared/JSON_REPORTS:/data/JSON_REPORTS
    depends_on: 
      - kafkazoo
  external_pull_data_service:
    build: ./external_pull_data_service
    # environment:
    #   - SCRIPT_NAME=report_generator.js
    volumes: 
      - /predix/shared/linux_shared/JSON_REPORTS:/data/JSON_REPORTS
    depends_on: 
      - kafkazoo
```

As you can see I added hostname: kafakazoo, and here is the new Kafka Client :

```js
const client = new kafka.Client("kafkazoo:2181");

const producer = new kafka.HighLevelProducer(client);
```

And this works perfectly

Thanks to [Michael Hampton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1068283/michael-hampton)

Comment: Kafka clients should connect to port 9092, not Zookeeper on 2181, and is there a reason you're building your own image rather than using existing ones?

Comment: Thanks for the insight, I'm doing my own image simply because i'm discovering Docker and I wanted to know how builing his own image works

Comment: Kafka is very complicated to build your own container, from what I've tried (the default property files won't work well in a container and aren't meant to form clusters). Learning about web applications or console apps is far easier

Comment: I agree, I switched to ches/kafka + zookeeper offical image since :) it works well now

Comment: Well, "confluentinc" images should be the "official" ones because that's the enterprise support company for it and has the largest staff of Kafka core developers

Comment: Sorry I missused the term "official" I meant an images well rated and documented.I found it intuitive that's why I used it over the confluentinc one

Comment: Got it. In any case, the Confluent images will generally always be up to date with the latest Kafka releases, as compared to that one. The other popular one is by wurstmeister